# Publish-Module fails with NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5) error : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: powershell, .net-core, nuget, dotnet-sdk, powershellget

I've upgraded to dotnet sdk version 3.1 and am trying to publish my powershell module. I am using powershell 5.1.

I run the command:

```
Publish-Module -Path "C:\sources\myModules\InstallationUtils\" -NuGetApiKey "xxxxxxx" -Repository internal.packages.org"
```

and get the error:

```
[C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\469d7c83-6e1a-4366-b948-6a415b0279be\Temp.csproj]
  Successfully created package
'C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\158464074\myModules\InstallationUtils\InstallationUtils.1.4.8.nupkg'.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5): error :
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
[C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\469d7c83-6e1a-4366-b948-6a415b0279be\Temp.csproj]
'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.1\PSModule.psm1:10944 char:17
+ ...             Publish-PSArtifactUtility @PublishPSArtifactUtility_Param ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToCreateCompressedModule,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

Is anyone have similar issues and managed to fix it? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have **a work around,** which involves replacing the old version of version nuget.exe in

> C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet\

with the latest version of nuget.exe .

I found the work around on [SQLDBAWithABeard](https://sqldbawithabeard.com/2019/11/26/fixing-the-failed-to-generate-the-compressed-file-for-module-cprogram-filesdotnetdotnet-exe-error-when-deploying-to-the-powershell-gallery-using-azure-devops/) but I am hoping that there is a better solution than this?